# LINQ side effects

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

is it possible to substitute a `foreach` loop with a lambda expression in LINQ (`.Select)`)?

```
List<int> l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
foreach (int i in l)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

To:

```
List<int> l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
l.Select(/* print to console */);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no Linq equivalent of foreach, although it is fairly easy to implement one yourself.

Eric Lippert gives a good description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach) of why this was not implemented in Linq itself.

However, if your collection is a List (which it appears to be in your example), you can use [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx):

```
myList.ForEach(item => Console.WriteLine(item));
```

Comment: I just added `.ToList()` at the end of the linq chain, and then `.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`

Answer (score 4):

For any `IEnumerable`, you can do:

```
items.Any(item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
    return false;
}
```

**But this would be utterly wrong! It's like using a shoe to hammer the nail.
Semantically, it does not make sense.**

Answer (score 2):

Use [List.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`List<T>.ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) method.

```
l.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine(i));
```

Answer (score 1):

List.ForEach uses action delegate. Henceforth that will the right choice.