# Filling a property of list from another property of list using lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a list  `List<BidResult> bidresults` filled with data. `BidResult` class is as below:

```
public class BidResult
{        
    public virtual int BidResultId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ProductName { get; set; }            
}
```

I have another list `List<Rating> ratings` which is empty and its properties are as follow:

```
public class Rating
{
    public virtual int RatingId { get; set; }            
    public virtual int BidResultId { get; set; }    

}
```

I need to populate 2nd list's `BidResultId` property using 1st list's `BidResultId` .
I know it can be done using a loop. But I need to do it using Lambda preferably.

**Edit:**

I tried below:

```
 List<Rating> ratings = bidResults.Select(bidResult => new Rating {RatingId = bidResult.BidResultId}).ToList();
```

but I am not able to access `BidResultId` from `bidResult`.

Please note `bidResult` is a strongly typed list. Adding a . after bidResult show lambda functions like select, foreach, single etc.

Comment: And what is algorithm of populating 2nd list?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy, 2nd list is just created and empty. Need to populate it.

Comment: Populate *how*? Is there one to one relation between BidResult and Rating? What should be used as RatingId?

Comment: I don't using a lambda is the best approach. Linq is designed to use lambdas without side effects, see [this Eric Lippert article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx) for the reasons why. However, this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632222/linq-side-effects) describes how to use `List.ForEach` to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I have read through every answer here and I have multiple questions.  1. Your last edit you have will produce a List<Rating> with each item in it having a BidResultId from the List<BidResult>.  So what are your truly looking for? Because if you use Ratings[0].BidResult you will see they are there.  Are you looking to create a sublist within the List<rating>?  if so please show a layout of what your desired output looks like or at least what code you would like to use to get your values (all of the values you want)

Comment: you are doing something wrong certainly

Answer (score 3):

Try this-

```
   List<Rating> ratings = bidResults.Select(bidResult => new Rating {RatingId = bidResult.BidResultId}).ToList();
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
   List<BidResult> bidResults = new List<BidResult>();
   bidResults.Add(new BidResult{BidResultId = 1,ProductName = "Product 1"});
   bidResults.Add(new BidResult { BidResultId = 2, ProductName = "Product 2" });
   bidResults.Add(new BidResult { BidResultId = 3, ProductName = "Product 3" });
   List<Rating> ratings = bidResults.Select(tempResult => new Rating { BidResultId = tempResult.BidResultId }).ToList();
```

Comment: nice idea, but wouldnt it be `new Rating {BidResultId = bidResult.BidResultId}`?

Comment: @paqogomez: It is not much clear from question, that what he wants to populate from the list. so this example is just to demonstrate that how he can populate a list from another list without using loop.

Comment: @Ramashankar, sorry it did not work. In code I m not able to access BidResultId using bidResult. Placing a . after bidResult show lambda functions like select,single,foreach etc. Please note bidResult is also a list. Any suggestion please.

Comment: @Toubi: what is not working here? Are you getting some kind of exception here? I hope the name bidresult & bidresults are not confusing here, because in the above example bidresults is a list but bidresult is just a variable, you can name it to anything else. For now I am updating it.

Answer (score 2):

If `bidResult => bidResult.` is giving you LINQ methods, then it's likely that the `bidResults` that you are running the `.Select` on is some type of `IEnumerable<<IEnumerable<BidResult>>` (i.e., a collection of a collection of `BidResult` objects.

For that, you can use a [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the outer list to flatten it out and expose the inner  collections to grab the `BidResults`:

```
ratings = bidResults
    .SelectMany(innerResults => innerResults)
    .Select(bidResult => new Rating { BidResultId = bidResult.BidResultId })
    .ToList();
```

To test this, I made a little console app:

```
List<Rating> ratings = null;
List<BidResult> tempList = new List<BidResult> {
    new BidResult { BidResultId = 1, ProductName = "First Product" },
    new BidResult { BidResultId = 2, ProductName = "Second Product" }
};

// creating a list of lists to simulate your issue
List<List<BidResult>> bidResults = new List<List<BidResult>> { tempList };

var i = 1; // just a variable to assign a rating id for the console output

ratings = bidResults
    .SelectMany(innerResults => innerResults) // required to flatten out the list of lists
    .Select(bidResult => new Rating { // bidResult is now a BidResult object
        RatingId = i++, 
        BidResultId = bidResult.BidResultId 
    }).ToList();

foreach (var result in ratings)
{
    Console.WriteLine("RatingID: {0} - BidResultID: {1}", result.RatingId, result.BidResultId);
}

Console.Read(); // don't exit until user hits a key
```

Which outputs the following:

```
RatingID: 1 - BidResultID: 1
RatingID: 2 - BidResultID: 2
```

For a graphical look at `SelectMany` and how it works, check out this blog post:

- [A Visual Look At The LINQ SelectMany Operator](http://www.codethinked.com/a-visual-look-at-the-linq-selectmany-operator)

Comment: Your `SelectMany` operator is useless in the above example. Why not simply use `ratings = tempList.Select(bidResult => new Rating...`?

Comment: @AndrewCoonce, I agree, that would be ideal, but if you read the OP, he is most likely selecting from a `List<List<T>>>` (see his edit), which is why my example is set up like that. Obviously, I would prefer to do a `tempList.Select(x => new Rating....)` here, but the OP's issue falls more in line with the example selecting from `bidResults` above. This, unfortunately, requires a semingly useless `SelectMany` to flatten out the nested lists.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution for your answer.

```
BidResult bidResult = new BidResult();
List<BidResult> bidResultList = new List<BidResult>();

// Lets Adding Some Data to bidResultList
bidResult.BidResultId = 1;
bidResult.ProductName = "A";
bidResultList.Add(bidResult);
bidResult.BidResultId = 2;
bidResult.ProductName = "B";
bidResultList.Add(bidResult);
bidResult.BidResultId = 3;
bidResult.ProductName = "C";
bidResultList.Add(bidResult);


List<Rating> ratingList = bidResultList.Select(bid => new Rating { BidResultId = bid.BidResultId }).ToList();
```

if you want to initiate ratingId (e.g. initiate by 7) then use above expression like this.

```
List<Rating> ratingList = bidResultList.Select(bid => new Rating { RatingId=7, BidResultId = bid.BidResultId }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started):

```
List<BidResult> bidresults = new List<BidResult>() {
    new BidResult() { BidResultId = 1, ProductName = "hello"},
    new BidResult() { BidResultId = 2, ProductName = "world"}
};

///////
Mapper.CreateMap<BidResult, Rating>();

var ratings = Mapper.Map<List<Rating>>(bidresults);
///////

foreach (var rating in ratings)
    Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", rating.BidResultId, rating.RatingId);
```

Outputting

```
1,0
2,0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Ratings> ratings = new List<Ratings>();
ratings.AddRange(bidresults.Select(bidResult => new Rating {RatingId = bidResult.BidResultId}).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramashankar's answer seems syntactically correct to me (though I'm unsure you really want to assign BidResult.BidResultId to Rating.RatingId).

So the remaining question is why this isn't working for you.  My best educated guess is a scoping conflict.  Is it possible the surrounding block of code already contains a variable named bidResult?  In this case, this variable would conflict with the lambda input operator.  This could explain why you get those lambda functions after the . with bidResult.  So the solution would be to change the name of the lambda input operator (like in Ramashankar's update).